# From Height Maps to Marching Cubes

Tags: unity-game-engine, procedural-generation, marching-cubes

i have been working on a project for a while now and have been following Sebastian Lague's tutorial on procedural mesh generation, but need to use marching cubes.

My end goal is to have a destructible  procedural terrain generation with noise.

I am working on Unity3D. I have recently learned what marching cubes is and have been researching it over the past few weeks. I have hit a roadblock and have no idea where to start.

I'm wondering is there any way to still use some Sebastian's code or do I have to completely restart? I am in general very confused.  I have read papers on it it but don't know how to implement it at all.

I have also looked at catlikecoding tutorial on marching squares, but still to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This tutorial looks nice: http://jamie-wong.com/2014/08/19/metaballs-and-marching-squares/

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Thanks for the link it was a interesting read!